# Setting country using command line in standalone tor distribution

Tags: configuration, windows, startup

My goal is to run tor as a socks proxy, mimicking user from Switzerland (on Windows).

With "Tor Browser" distribution I was able to set country using `torrc` file by adding:

```
ExitNodes {ch} StrictNodes 1
```

For some reason, when using standalone "Windows Expert Bundle" distribution and passing `ExitNodes` as comman line argument this no longer works (bootstrap does not seem to complete).

Here is how I run tor and output:

```
C:\Users\Username\workspace\test>tor\Tor\tor.exe --SocksPort 9050 --StrictNodes 1 --ExitNodes "{ch}"
Dec 31 22:03:29.187 [notice] Tor 0.4.4.6 (git-2a8b789ea6f308d0) running on Windows 8 [or later] with Libevent 2.1.11-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1i, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma N/A, and Libzstd N/A.
Dec 31 22:03:29.189 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Dec 31 22:03:29.213 [notice] Configuration file "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\tor\torrc" not present, using reasonable defaults.
Dec 31 22:03:29.215 [warn] Path for GeoIPFile (<default>) is relative and will resolve to C:\Users\Username\workspace\test\<default>. Is this what you wanted?
Dec 31 22:03:29.215 [warn] Path for GeoIPv6File (<default>) is relative and will resolve to C:\Users\Username\workspace\test\<default>. Is this what you wanted?
Dec 31 22:03:29.218 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Dec 31 22:03:29.218 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Dec 31 22:03:29.000 [warn] Failed to open GEOIP file C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\tor\geoip.
Dec 31 22:03:29.000 [warn] We've been configured to use (or avoid) nodes in certain countries, and we need GEOIP information to figure out which ones they are.
Dec 31 22:03:29.000 [warn] Failed to open GEOIP file C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\tor\geoip6.
Dec 31 22:03:29.000 [warn] We've been configured to use (or avoid) nodes in certain countries, and we need GEOIP information to figure out which ones they are.
Dec 31 22:03:29.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
Dec 31 22:03:31.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
Dec 31 22:03:58.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION:**

Adding `--GeoIPv6File <geoip6 file from distribution> --GeoIPFile "<geoip file from distribution>"` worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Failed to open GEOIP file C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\tor\geoip` is the important one here. If tor can't open the geoip file, it doesn't have any location data for any relay.

Since the path is relative, you need to run `tor.exe` from the correct directory. So use the `cd` command to change directories, probably to `C:\Users\Username\workspace\test\tor\Tor`, before running `tor.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason for using command line parameters instead of torrc?

I'd guess that cli parameters have precedence default settings, which it is using:
`[notice] Configuration file "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\tor\torrc" not present, using reasonable defaults.`

It's also reporting it's not finding geoip:

```
Dec 31 22:03:29.215 [warn] Path for GeoIPFile (<default>) is relative and will resolve to C:\Users\Username\workspace\test\<default>. Is this what you wanted?
Dec 31 22:03:29.215 [warn] Path for GeoIPv6File (<default>) is relative and will resolve to C:\Users\Username\workspace\test\<default>. Is this what you wanted?
```

I'd suggest to make a clean install, outside user profile, and use torrc. U should have better chances to get it working.